# How can I get revision from other workspace in perforce by command line?

Tags: perforce

I have a workspace "template" that get some file in local. 
I can use gui to create a new workspace, right-click, get revision..., select "template". 
Then, the new workspace's local file = template's local file. The file's version is also equal.

How can i use command line do the same thing?

Answer (score 1):

The equivalent of the "get revision" operation you're talking about is to use the client spec `template` as the revision specifier on a `p4 sync`:

```
p4 sync FILE@template
```

This is commonly used to recreate the state of another client for purposes of recreating a build.  The client essentially acts like a `label` for whatever revisions it has synced.  To sync the entire workspace instead of that one specific `FILE`, simply use `p4 sync @template`.

Note that this is completely separate from the concept of using the client spec as a "template" for the `View` of a new client:

```
p4 client -t template
```

This will create a new client spec that copies its `View` from the `template` client, but the specific set of revisions it's synced to (commonly called the "have list", i.e. the set of revisions referenced by `#have` within that client and by `@client` from any other context) is not in any way bound to the template client (unless a `ChangeView` is used, but that's a whole other thing).

Since these are separate operations it is not necessary to do one in order to do the other.